# are 'optimized' .pyo files unsafe?

Tags: python

I found out to my horror that `python -O` strips out assert statements. I use asserts anywhere and everywhere, and I think of asserts (like exceptions in general) as a form of flow control.

Python people: are `python -O` and `.pyo` files considered safe? Is it unsafe to rely on asserts?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: same sense of 'safe' as checking your buffer lengths in C. 'unsafe' coding leads to unspecified behavior and, in some cases, security vulnerabilities.

Comment: `python -O` is considered safe.  If you put critical control flow into asserts, you're making `python -O` unsafe, which is bad.

Comment: `assert` should be used only for tests.

Comment: @JBernardo why only for tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good idea to rely on asserts.  It's not a good idea to use asserts as flow control.  The reason is exactly as you describe: they can be disabled.  The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) says it simply:

> Assert statements are a convenient way to insert debugging assertions into a program

Asserts are for debugging, not to be relied on in production code.

Answer (score 2):

Assertions are meant for catching bugs, not for flow control. It's therefore perfectly valid for an optimiser to strip them out because,  by the time your code ships, *those bugs should have been removed.*

If you're using them as a general purpose exception raiser, I would suggest that you're using them wrongly.

There's a good page discussing this on the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) and I point you to the last bit specifically:

> One important reason why assertions should only be used for self-tests of the program is that **assertions can be disabled at compile time.**
>
> If Python is started with the -O option, then assertions will be stripped out and not evaluated. So if code uses assertions heavily, but is performance-critical, then there is a system for turning them off in release builds.

Comment: ok, but the very next line of the wiki is 'but don't do this unless it's really necessary'.

Comment: @amwinter: it's saying "don't use `-O` unless it's necessary". It's not saying the use of assertions should be suborned for the purposes of flow control :-) I wouldn't even _catch_ assertion exceptions in the code since, if you knew what to do in that case, you would have planned for it and recovered (with either a _different_ exception or with pre-check code).

Comment: but asserts are more readable and easier to type than other kinds of exceptions. And `python -O` does basically nothing. I'd much rather say goodbye to python -O than to asserts.

Comment: @Will -- given a feature that helps catch bugs, disabling it is insecure.

Comment: @paxdiablo even uncaught, assertions are flow control: they print the stack and kill the process (rather than continuing into dangerous waters).

Comment: @Will I'm with you on doing input validation but AssertionError is totally an exception, I don't understand why you're saying it's not

Comment: @amwinter, I'd call uncaught assertions less flow control and more program exit due to catastrophic assumption failure :-) In any case, `-O` does _not_ do nothing, it strips out asserts as per the documentation, possibly allowing your code to run faster. The fact that Python lets you do this supports my contention on how asserts should be used. If you want the assertions left in, follow the advice of the wiki and don't use `-O`. Your code _may_ run slower but you'll feel safer. But don't consider that a failure of `-O`, it's more that you're not using assertions as intended.